# How can I find the equilibrium constant Kp without temperature?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium

The question I'm looking at is [image]

I found that that Kc = 139M^-1, but how can I determine Kp? There is no temperature given, but I was told that it is still possible to calculate.

Comment: Why do you think you need the temperature in this case to calculate $K_p$?

Comment: HINT - Assume ideal gas behavior.

Answer (score 0):

$K_p=K_c(RT)^{\Delta n_g}$(try to prove this yourself) where $\Delta n_g$ is number of gaseous products -Number of gaseous reactants.

In your question, $\Delta n_g=0$ so $K_p=K_c=2.43$

Comment: Thank you! If the number of gaseous products was not 0, would this still be solvable? For example, in this question: https://i.gyazo.com/0cf8ffd4c95e126583a973e3b768b30a.png

Comment: Yes. Kc can directly be found.Hint: No of moles directly proportional to concentration. Kp = Kx * (P_total/(total number of moles))^∆ng